# Rewrite a URL that's already been redirected?

Tags: url, url-rewriting, redirect, masking

I'm running an Apache2 web server with a dynamic IP address. I bought *exampledomain.net*, and I use [no-ip.com](http://www.no-ip.com/services/managed_dns/plus_dynamic_dns.html)'s domain-update service to redirect any visitors to my current ip address (endnote #1). For example, someone visits *exampledomain.net* and they get redirected to *73.181.57.34*. It works like a charm. However, it isn't all that user-friendly. Can I rewrite the redirected, ip-address URL?

I tried these rewrite rules in the root folder's .htaccess...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^73\.181\.57\.34:88
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.exampledomain.net/$1 [L,NC]
# I simplified the RewriteCond. I would use regex in a real situation.
```

Of course, this creates an infinite loop. The user visits *www.exampledomain.net*. They're redirected to *73.181.57.34:88* by no-ip. Apache redirects them to *www.exampledomain.net* which redirects them back to *73.181.57.34:88*... so on and so forth.

I'm a noob when it comes to rewriting, but is there a way to rewrite a URL without redirecting?

I tried these rewrite rules too (a shot in the dark)...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^73\.181\.57\.34:88
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ my.exampledomain.net/$1 [L,NC]
# I'd read that Apache replied with a redirect header when you include http
```

Of course, this doesn't work because my.exampledomain.net doesn't really exist.

Thanks!

---

(1) No-IP works like this: You download and install their dynamic update client on your server. Every couple of minutes it polls your server for its current external ip address. If it's changed, it updates your server's ip address in no-ip's records.

Answer (score 1):

No. For example I can't show you my website and have http://yourbank.example.com in the address bad.